# No route matches [PUT], resource and method are defined though

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest

I'm using postman to make a `PUT` or `PATCH` request, but it says `No route matches [PUT] "/api/registrations"`

my URL looks like this

```
http://localhost:3000/api/registrations?id=5&status=approved"
```

My routes.rb file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  scope :api do
    resources :professors
    resources :registrations
    resources :schedules
    resources :notifications
    resources :users
    resources :meetings
    resources :courses
    resources :students
  end
end
```

I have a defined `update` method in my RegistrationsController and My POST and GET routes work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL you're using is incorrent. You should not pass `id` in query, but in path.

A correct URL is

```
http://localhost:3000/api/registrations/5?status=approved
```

Rails sets id as last element of a resourceful route.

[Docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions) say:

> `resources :photos`
>
> (...)
>
> `PATCH/PUT`   `/photos/:id`   `photos#update`     update a specific photo

Comment: perfect. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Run `rails routes` on the command line to get the proper URL pattern and it's matching Controller action.